Boxwood moth plan for my shrub in NY State
My neighborhood seems to have a very recent infestation of boxwood moths.
By the time I noticed it, it was pretty late.  I brought in a great company that the guy I use for cleanups and mowing recommended.  I decided to save one important shrub, and let another one go.  They did a spray and a soil treatment, and that successfully saved the boxwoods that I wanted saved, along the walk in the front garden.  The one I let go, on the side of the house, that never really felt to me like it belonged there, was a pile of dry sticks in short order.
This is the outcome I was looking for, but it was a little pricey, and I don't want to have to bring these guys in year after year.  I'm looking for help developing a good treatment plan for boxwoods in northwestern NY state, about 2 minutes south of the Lake as the crow flies.  If it makes a difference, the shrub is about 30 yards from a stream.  My experience with insecticides is essentially zero.  I'm looking for advice on both the agent to use, and an application schedule.
